# Ре-инициализация Slick-слайдера в POP-up окне

Tags: slider, slick.js, popup

Slick-слайдер в POP-up окне. Работает, но не сразу: нет ре-инициализации..
Скриншот: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт инициализации слайдера:

```js
var $status = $('.count');
var $slickElement = $('.slider_all');

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

    //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
    var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
    $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
});


$slickElement.slick({
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  appendArrows:'.wrap_arrows',
  prevArrow:'<span class="strelka_nazad_header"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>',
  nextArrow:'<span class="strelka_vpered_header"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>'
});
```

Скрипт открытия POP-UP окна для Slick-слайдера:

```js
$(".popup").magnificPopup({type:"image"});
$(".popup_content").magnificPopup({
  type:"inline",
  midClick: true
});


$(".portfolio_item").each(function(i) {
  $(this).find("a").attr("href", "#work_" + i);

  $slickElement.slick('refresh'); - ТУТ Так ПРОБОВАЛ - РЕЗУЛЬТАТА НЕТ! //////////////////
  
  $(this).find(".popup_window_SLACK_portfolio").attr("id", "work_" + i);
  
  $('.slider_all').slick('refresh'); - ТУТ Так ПРОБОВАЛ - ОПЯТЬ РЕЗУЛЬТАТА НЕТ! /////////////
});
```

Где нужно выполнить РЕ-Инициализацию слайдера, что бы при загрузке страницы отобразился первый слайд  (ре-инициализировался)?

P.S. В консоли ошибок нет..